# Building zxing on MinGW fails with "TestFactoryRegistry.h: No such file or directory", even though CppUnit is installed

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, zxing, cppunit

I'm trying to compile the C++ port of zxing on Windows using MinGW, but the build fails with:

```
build\core\tests\src\TestRunner.cpp:21:52: fatal error: cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h: No such file or directory
```

---

**Edit**

I installed CppUnit and now I have the header file at `c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\include\cppunit\extensions\TestFactoryRegistry.h`, however the build still fails with `TestFactoryRegistry.h: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the SConscript file was assuming a wrong path for CppUnit.

I needed to change this line in the SConscript file:

```
cppunit_include = ['/opt/local/include/']
```

To:

```
cppunit_include = ['c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/']
```